# REGEX to get whole paragraph from string extracted from PDF

Tags: php, regex, paragraph

I am a newby on regex.

I have a PHP code that extracts all text from a PDF file and store in a string variable. 
There is a specific paragraph on page #2 that I need to get. I am trying to use regex to get the text until periods, but the problem is that inside this paragraph there are a lot of periods, and the regex is only matching the first sentence.

This is what the PDF part I need to get looks like:
[image]

I need to get all the paragraph that is aligned on the right. All of them start with this sentence "AGRAVO DE EXCECUÇÃO PENAL". But the end differs from one to another.

This is how the string variable value looks like (the part I need is in bold):
*"PODER JUDICIÁRIO

TRIBUNAL DE JUSTIçA DO ESTADO DE SãO PAULO

13ª CâMARA DE DIREITO CRIMINAL

AGRAVO DE EXECUçãO PENAL Nº 000000000000 - VOTO Nº 0000 2

VOTO Nº 00000

AGRAVO DE EXECUçãO PENAL Nº 0000000000000000000

AGRAVANTE: MINISTéRIO PúBLICO DO ESTADO DE SãO PAULO

AGRAVADA: NAME

**AGRAVO DE EXECUÇÃO PENAL EXECUçãO CRIMINAL PLEITO DE MANUTENçãO DO CARáTER HEDIONDO DO CRIME DE TRáFICO PRIVILEGIADO, A FIM DE MODIFICAR OS CáLCULOS NOVO ENTENDIMENTO DO C. STF EXTERNADO NO JULGAMENTO DO HC Nº 118.533/MS, NO SENTIDO DE AFASTAR A NATUREZA HEDIONDA DO TRáFICO PRIVILEGIADO DE DROGAS DECISãO DO JUíZO EM CONSONâNCIA COM O ENTENDIMENTO ESPECíFICO DO PLENáRIO DO C. STF, QUE Há DE PREVALECER AGRAVO NãO PROVIDO.**

CUIDA-SE DE AGRAVO DE EXECUçãO PENAL INTERPOSTO PELO M IN IS T ÉR IO P Ú BLIC O D O E ST A DO D E S Ã O P A ULO CONTRA DECISãO PROFERIDA PELO JUíZO DO DEECRIM DA 6ª RAJ (COMARCA DE RIBEIRãO PRETO), QUE INDEFERIU PEDIDO DE RETIFICAçã"*

Comment: Can you post a text version of your pdf data?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Ok, just made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to be working for your content,

```
[A-Z]+.*\.\s*\n
```

Basically start your match with an upper case and capture anything including any periods in the middle of text and stop at last dot `.`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EEV3HO/5)**

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It works for the example text, but for others, it seems to match also other parts of the text. Take a look [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EEV3HO/3)

Comment: @henriqueromao: It will match similar lines but if you want to restrict further, then you will have to apply something in regex that distinguishes it from the rest of the content. Like to avoid matching others, you can have `\n` at the end of regex to make it match only if dot is followed by a newline.

Comment: Now it worked for all the texts. Thank's I rather accept your answer!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Just write me back if you see it getting stuck in any case.

Comment: Ok! Thank's again!

Answer (score 1):

Since the sentence goes until the end of the line, you can use a multi-line match (`m` modifier) to get `^` and `$` to match begining and end of line for each line. Then this simple regex should work:

```
/^AGRAVO DE EXECUÇÃO PENAL.*$/m
```

e.g.

```
preg_match('/^AGRAVO DE EXECUÇÃO PENAL.*$/m', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Output:

```
AGRAVO DE EXECUÇÃO PENAL EXECUçãO CRIMINAL PLEITO DE MANUTENçãO DO CARáTER HEDIONDO DO CRIME DE TRáFICO PRIVILEGIADO, A FIM DE MODIFICAR OS CáLCULOS NOVO ENTENDIMENTO DO C. STF EXTERNADO NO JULGAMENTO DO HC Nº 118.533/MS, NO SENTIDO DE AFASTAR A NATUREZA HEDIONDA DO TRáFICO PRIVILEGIADO DE DROGAS DECISãO DO JUíZO EM CONSONâNCIA COM O ENTENDIMENTO ESPECíFICO DO PLENáRIO DO C. STF, QUE Há DE PREVALECER AGRAVO NãO PROVIDO.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NcC68)